# Why do parenthesis make such a difference?

Tags: python

I wrote a code that returns the count of distinct case-insensitive alphabetic characters and numeric digits that occur more than once in the input string. Here's my code:

```
def duplicate_count(text):
    sum_low = 0
    dic_low = []
    sum_up = 0
    dic_up = []
    sum_num = 0
    dic_num = []
    total = 0
    for i in text:
    if i.isalpha():
        if i.islower() and text.count(i) > 1 and i not in dic_low:
            dic_low.append(i)
            sum_low = sum_low + 1
        elif i.isupper() and text.count(i) > 1 and i not in dic_up:
            dic_up.append(i)
            sum_up = sum_up + 1
    elif i.isdigit() and text.count(i) > 1 and i not in dic_num:
        dic_num.append(i)
        sum_num = sum_num + 1
    total = sum_low + sum_up + sum_num
    print (total)
```

The problem is, I noticed that when I missed parenthesis after "if i.isalpha()" this code worked perfectly with alphabetic characters but appeared to ignore digits, so for instance if I passed "aabbcdeBBAA" it printed "4", but if the argument was "11336" it printed "0". Later I found out that the parenthesis had been missed and corrected it, and the code started to work normally, but I still don't understand what the problem was. There was no any TraceBack, so I guess the problem was in missing parenthesis. Why does it make such a big difference?

PS: sorry if the code is too weird, I'm new to programming and just started to learn coding.
Thank you!

Comment: can you give an example with and without parenthesis? I don't understand where you put them or where you forgot them

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`i.isalpha` is an object (the method `isalpha` of your string `i`). It is not `Null`, nor does it correspond to a falsy value like `0`, `""`, `[]` etc., so if checked for its boolean value, it is evaluated as `True`.

Only by adding `()`, you actually *call*  that method.

A practical tip: There is a common beginners' mistake with file handles: `myfile.close` doesn't close the file `myfile`, only `myfile.close()` does. But the first statement is syntactically valid and will not raise an error. You just might be wondering why the file you just wrote is empty...

Comment: To make it more explicit while running the risk of oversimplifying, without the parenthesis you are evaluating the function object itself (`>>> i.isalpha` returns `<function isalpha>` and `>>> bool(i.isalpha)` returns `True`), but you are not running the function. By adding the parenthesis you are running the function and getting the return value of it's evaluation of `i` (whether or not it is only made of alphabet characters).

Comment: Thank you so much! A very clear and simple explanation, now I got it!

Answer (score 2):

If you write `i.isalpha` means you are referring to the function, not actually calling the function, you need to add `()` at the end to *call* the function

```
>>> i = 'some text'
>>> obj = i.isalpha   # just reference not actually call
>>> obj
<function str.isalpha>
>>> obj()    # adding '()' executes the function
False
>>> i.isalpha()  
False
```

Comment: Thank you for your explanation! A very clear answer!